# Handheld recorder for a journalist?

Tags: portable-recorder

A friend recently asked me what handheld recorder to buy as a journalist. I am not sure what a radio journalist needs, but my thoughts are that it needs to be able to go both omni and carioid depending on the situation. If the interview is held at crowded areas then cardoid could be more useful, and if the area is quiet and the journalist just likes to keep the recorder on the table then omni could be useful.

This is just my thoughts but i am very curious about how you guys think about this? What would you look for in a journalist handheld recorder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sony PCM-M10                      .

I don't think she'll need cardioids, if the point is to just record tangible conversations (for which the PCM-M10 is rather fine).

A perhaps better (if mono recording is preferred) option for hand-held recording would be a mono microphone of some sort and a recorder with a XLR mic input.

Then there's the H6 which has "everything", although it comes at a price (http://www.zoom.co.jp/products/h6/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do own the PCM-M10 myself and use it for ambience recording. The only reason i have not recommended it yet is because its only omni. But its true what you say, and at really crowded places an external microphone connected to the "linein mic input" might be usefull.